# why my code does not load the kml file ..(it is the simplest way)

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, kml

this is my google-map code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=0.3,maximum-scale=5.0,user-scalable=yes">

    </head>
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">

<style type="text/css">
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
</style>
<!--<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;"> </div>-->
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>


<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAA-7cuV3vqp7w6zUNiN_F4uBRi_j0U6kJrkFvY4-OX2XYmEAa76BSNz0ifabgugotzJgrxyodPDmheRA&sensor=false"type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var aFn;
//**********
function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        var g = new GGeoXml("b.kml");
                map.addOverlay(g);
                var center=new GLatLng(37.42228990140251,-122.0822035425683);
        map.setCenter(center, 0);

}
}
//*************



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my b.kml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>Simple placemark</name>
    <description>Attached to the ground. Intelligently places itself 
       at the height of the underlying terrain.</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

why cann't show the point ..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is that you were missing `<Document></Document>` -- but looking at the docs I'm not sure that's right.

Is `b.kml` being served with the mime type `application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml`? Looking at the documentation, it seems like that's a requirement:
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html#kml_server

other thoughts:

- give the full url to `b.kml` in the `new GGeoXml("b.kml")` call
- fire up firebug and see if there's a successful request to `b.kml`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the publicly accessible url to your .kml file.

You won't see a request for it in firebug. The maps api requests a resource from google and passes the name of your kml file. google pulls it in to thier servers and processes it and delivers json to the map in your page.

IMHO. YMMV